# SEHException thrown in a non-.NET application

Tags: .net, c++, windows, mfc

I am writing an MFC application that doesn't use .NET (CLR support is set to *No Common Language Runtime support* in the project settings). However, I get an `SEHException` thrown when I quit the application in Release build. Debug build gives me an assertion error, but the  error window disappears in about half a second after it pops up (something I haven't encountered before either) so I don't get a chance to look at it.

So the main question is: how can an application that doesn't have any managed code throw an Interop.SEHException?

Comment: Does the exception always occur, or only when you run it from Visual Studio (i.e., when a debugger is attached)?

Comment: It always occurs. When I run it from VS the exception box comes up. When I run it as a stand-alone app, however, a C Runtime Error pops up, but, again, for only a second.

Comment: The disappearing exc. box is rather odd, do you have some software running that dismisses certain boxes? Is it possible to use deduction: remove all but a bit and add piece by piece until error re-occurs? Possible driver issue (I had somewhat similar behavior once with a corrupted windows driver update)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An application without managed code can throw a SEHException because structured exception handling (SEH) is part of Win32, and predates the CLR. Here's a link from [January 1997 giving a crash course (hah!) on Win32 SEH](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/Exception/Exception.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Ah, fixed it. The problem was that I was calling my exiting code (that included a call to `PostQuitMessage()`) twice from two separate threads. The disappearing box was due to the fact that very soon after the exception was thrown `exit(0)` was called and the program terminated.